# Can execute a stored procedure in management studio for user without login, but cannot connect through asp.net getting error Login failed for user

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have created a user with name as testuser in SQL Server 2008 of type "user without login"

Then I created as stored procedure, and granted execute permission to 'testuser'

I am able to execute the stored procedure in management studio, but I cannot do the same from asp.net application, is it possible ??? the code is as under

/* SQL Server 2008 */

```
CREATE user testuser without login

CREATE procedure test_app (@myempid int, @mybasic int out )
AS
    select @mybasic = basic
    from employee_master
    where employeeID = @myempid
```

I execute the above procedure as under

```
EXECUTE AS USER='testuser'
GO

DECLARE @emp_bas int
DECLASE @emp_id int

set @emp_id = 1

EXEC test_app @emp_id, @emp_bas out
SELECT @emp_bas
GO
```

I am able to execute the stored procedure with testuser credential, but when I try the same from asp.net I get error Login failed for user 'testuser'

The code is as under:

```
strConnString = "Data Source=mypc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=testuser"

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "test_app";

cmd.Parameters.Add("employeeID", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtempid.Text;

SqlParameter parameterReturnValue = new SqlParameter("emp_bas", SqlDbType.Int, 10);
parameterReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterReturnValue);

retval = 0;

try
{
    con.Open();
    retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int returnvalue = (int)cmd.Parameters["emp_bas"].Value;
    retval = returnvalue;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}

return retval;
```

Comment: Are your SQL set to receive outside commands? See in you SQL configuration if it can accept external calls.